# Apache Spark DAG creator

Tags: apache-spark, directed-acyclic-graphs

Can someone help me with the class which deals with the DAG creation in apache spark. I tried go through the documentation and the core libraries, could not find the classes related to DAG creation.

https://github.com/apache/spark

Comment: Help you with what precisely ? What is your question ?

Comment: Have a look at DAGScheduler under org.apache.spark.scheduler

Comment: Hi Michael yes I have gone through the dag scheduler class but I do not see anything which creates the dag

Comment: I will go through the class again as you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Michael for the pointers

I got the answer

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/scheduler/DAGScheduler.scala